# Overlapping CAShapeLayers transparency

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I want to create overlapping `CAShapeLayer`s where they both create transparent 'areas' in the top view. But the overlapping shapes get colored again.

I achieved the overlapping transparent shapes without using `CAShapeLayer`s, but using `drawRect` instead. But the problem with `drawRect` is that I can't animate the 'areas'.

With `drawRect` I used `kCGBlendMode.Clear`. Is this possible by only using `CAShapeLayer`s?

I want the blue area below to be transparent.

[image]

Comment: You should poste some images of what you want to achieve.

Comment: if you want it to be transparent, set the color as [UIColor colorWithRed: 1 green: 0 blue: 0 alpha: 0];

Comment: That does not work :)